Nginx's limit_req + fail2ban: IP addresses are getting banned yet can still access the site
I have successfully set up Nginx's limit_req module so that when anyone attempts to access a PHP file on our server (which we don't host at all), they get a 503. See this question about my setup, including config.
Now I want to build upon this by adding a fail2ban jail for this, so that people who attempt to access PHP files simply get banned for a while. I've seemingly got it working: when I access a PHP address multiple times in a row I do see fail2ban log entries about adding my address to the jail. However, I am still able to access the website just fine, I'm not really banned at all.
/etc/fail2ban/filter.d/nginx-limit-req.conf:
[Definition]
ngx_limit_req_zones = deny_rules
failregex = ^\s*\[[a-z]+\] \d+#\d+: \*\d+ limiting requests, excess: [\d\.]+ by zone "(?:%(ngx_limit_req_zones)s)", client: <HOST>,
ignoreregex =
datepattern = {^LN-BEG}

/etc/fail2ban/jail.local:
[nginx-limit-req]
port    = http,https
logpath = %(nginx_error_log)s
enabled = true
bantime  = 2h
maxretry = 1

When I repeatedly access a .php address on our server, here's what happens. I do see the ban coming in just fine:
tail -f /var/log/fail2ban.log
2024-06-03 10:38:33,921 fail2ban.filter         [3816728]: INFO    [nginx-limit-req] Found 81.204.117.221 - 2024-06-03 10:38:33
2024-06-03 10:38:34,242 fail2ban.actions        [3816728]: NOTICE  [nginx-limit-req] 81.204.117.221 already banned

And yes, the address is added to the firewall:
iptables -S | grep f2b:
iptables -S | grep f2b
-N f2b-nginx-limit-req
-N f2b-sshd
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -j f2b-nginx-limit-req
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 22 -j f2b-sshd
-A f2b-nginx-limit-req -s 81.204.117.221/32 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

What piece of the puzzle am I missing here? Why can I still access the site? We're using fail2ban v0.11.2 on Debian 11, with UFW behind the scenes.

To see (or modify) IPv6 rules you need ip6tables not iptables. You should get blocked for a while, but on some systems IPv6 addresses change automatically in as little as an hour, so the block won't persist as it usually does on IPv4.

You're right, the IPv6 stuff seems to have been a red herring. I'm at a different location now where I only have an IPv4 address, and the problem still exists. I've modified my question to remove the focus on IPv6.

Well about IPv6. You will have better success if you block a whole /64 subnet at a time. But that is outside the scope the question. :-)

Ok, I found the problem: the site is proxied by CloudFlare. So while we're blocking the user's real IP address (due to us using Nginx's realip module), it's not the user's real IP address connecting to the webserver, and so iptables is not blocking the user.
